# meteor.js with autoform: production fails

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, npm, meteorite

I've looked all over, getting the following error ONLY in production (my own server and meteor's public option):

> Uncaught Error: afFieldIsInvalid helper must be used within an autoForm block helper

This is only happening on the server. I'm using demeteorize to push the package, but witness the same problem when pushing to clientportal.meteor.com.

Running this code locally, I haven't seen the error. My first thought is a bundling issue, which is disturbing, but hoping I made another deployment mistake.

To reiterate, works perfectly on my local machine. Put together on my Mac, reinstalled fibers.

Can't think of anything else relevant but happy to provide more.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Ubuntu when you built this on your Mac? Is that your production environment?

Comment: As a suggestion: try bundling with debug option: `meteor bundle debug` to see if it is a problem of minifier/linker

Comment: Yes, sorry. Ubuntu environment. Thanks for the debug recommend, will update.

Comment: Huzzah! That indeed was the problem. Thanks for the quick idea...now to figure out what's conflicting :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above was the result of bundling errors. Thanks to imslavko for pointing out the debug option, confirmed the problem. I was able to double confirm by using the npm node-inspector on my own server.

This appears to be an issue with the meteorite autoform package and nesting forms. I'm going to track it down and submit the info to their github.